# Can .Find method return wrong results in multi-user environment

Tags: c#, entity-framework

It is mentioned on this MSDN link the following about the `.Find()` method

> If the entity is not found in the context then a query will be sent to
>   the database to find the entity there. Null is returned if the entity
>   is not found in the context or in the database. Find is different from
>   using a query in two significant ways:
>
> • A round-trip to the database
>   will only be made if the entity with the given key is not found in the
>   context.
>
> • Find will return entities that are in the Added state. That
>   is, Find will return entities that have been added to the context but
>   have not yet been saved to the database.

But can this cause a problem? Let's say that an object was marked as Added state, but before saving it to the database an exception occurred. So the find might return the object with Added state, which have not been saved to the database later on.

Second concern, what if the .Find found an object in the context and that object was updated in the database just after finding it, so the object version on the context will be old?

So what are the benefits I can get from using `.Find()` instead of doing my search based on the primary key using `.Where` or `.firstordefault(a=>a.primarykey ==id)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the docs state that Find...

> Uses the primary key value to attempt to find an entity tracked by the context. If the entity is not in the context then a query will be executed and evaluated against the data in the data source,

So it searches the cache first. If what's in your cache is old (or doesn't exist in the database - and maybe never will) then that's what you get. It ONLY does a query if it can't find the entity in the cache. I wouldn't say it returns the "wrong" thing because of what it's defined to do. If you need to find data that might be changed by another user or that's guaranteed to exist in the database you'll want to stick with a query.